# Unable to use ldap authentication in opencast

Tags: java, spring-security, ldap, osgi

We are trying to use ldap authentication on an opencast server (version 3.7) and have made configuration steps described in the [manual](https://docs.opencast.org/develop/admin/configuration/security.ldap/). It doesn't work, even the opencast web page is inaccessible, showing error 403 (Forbidden). If we revert previous configuration, the page works normally. We have done extensive search about Spring Security which is in use here but the configurations and suggested modifications described in these posts are so much different than the one used in opencast that these posts are of little use to us, inexperienced in Java environment.
The error in `/var/log/opencast.log` says:

`2019-02-21 15:27:14,879 | ERROR | (SpringSecurityConfigurationArtifactInstaller:102) - Unable to refresh spring security configuration file /etc/opencast/security/mh_default_org.xml: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#8' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [8]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#8': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ldapAuthProvider' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapAuthProvider' defined in OSGi resource[file:/etc/opencast/security/mh_default_org.xml|bnd.id=102|bnd.sym=matterhorn-kernel]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authoritiesPopulator' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authoritiesPopulator': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.osgi.service.ServiceUnavailableException: service matching filter=[(&(objectClass=org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapAuthoritiesPopulator)(instanceId=<our_ID>))] unavailable`

Note that `<our_ID>` is configured to point to proper `org.opencastproject.userdirectory.ldap-<our_ID>.cfg` file as per the manual. The opencast server is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and opencast is installed via apt from the opencast repository `https://pkg.opencast.org/debian`. The ldap server is normally accessible with the `ldapsearch` tool from the opencast server.

**EDIT:** According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/opencast.org/forum/#!topic/users/WmP9ic0XnrM), it is necessary to have some attribute in the ldap directory which tells what roles the authenticated user has. Can somebody please shed some more light on this?

Comment: I actually have LDAP working but encountered this on some of the worker nodes. I thought maybe this was caused by SE Linux, so I set it to "permissive" mode, but this did not help. Running CentOS 8.